# Different color for routes in folium map in python

Tags: routes, folium

I am trying to make a route map with Folium and API key. Everything looks good. However, I am trying to set different color for each route in the map. I have two routes. Here is my code. I would like to get some help and comments for improving and figuring out my problem. Thanks in advance. Here is my code in Python:

```
import requests
import folium
import pandas as pd

def get_directions_response(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, mode='drive'):
   url = "https://route-and-directions.p.rapidapi.com/v1/routing"
   key = "YOUR API KEY"
   host = "route-and-directions.p.rapidapi.com"
   headers = {"X-RapidAPI-Key": key, "X-RapidAPI-Host": host}
   querystring = {"waypoints":f"{str(lat1)},{str(long1)}|{str(lat2)},{str(long2)}","mode":mode}
   response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
   return response
response = get_directions_response(52.4013, 4.5425, 52.402, 4.5426)


location0 = (-23.6094538,   -46.4890429)
location1 = (-23.5289738,   -46.4557977)
location2 = (-23.5359445,   -46.4418587)
location3 = (-23.5986146,   -46.4363118)
location4 = (-23.5282782,   -46.4343494)
location5 = (-23.5282782,   -46.4343494)
route1 = [ location0,location1,location2,location3, location4,location5]

location6 = ( -23.6036487,  -46.4544768)
location7 = (-23.5397986,   -46.4467403)
location8 = (-23.5571792,   -46.4490686)
location9 = (-23.5342108,   -46.4445623)
location10 = (-23.5571792,  -46.4490686)
route2 = [location6,location7,location8, location9,location10]

route = [route1, route2]

#----------------
responses = []
for i in range(len(route)):
    for n in range(len(route[i])-1):
        lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = route[i][n][0], route[i][n][1], route[i][n+1][0], route[i][n+1][1]
        response = get_directions_response(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, mode='drive')
        responses.append(response)


def create_map(responses, route):
   m = folium.Map()
   df = pd.DataFrame()
   for i in range(len(route)):
       for point in route[i]:
           folium.Marker(point).add_to(m) 
       for response in responses:
           mls = response.json()['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
           points = [(i[1], i[0]) for i in mls[0]]
           folium.PolyLine(points, weight=5, opacity=1, color='red').add_to(m)
           temp = pd.DataFrame(mls[0]).rename(columns={0:'Lon', 1:'Lat'})[['Lat', 'Lon']]
           df = pd.concat([df, temp])
   sw = df[['Lat', 'Lon']].min().values.tolist()
   sw = [sw[0]-0.0005, sw[1]-0.0005]
   ne = df[['Lat', 'Lon']].max().values.tolist()
   ne = [ne[0]+0.0005, ne[1]+0.0005]
   m.fit_bounds([sw, ne])
   return m
m = create_map(responses, route)
m.save('./route_map.html')
```

I am trying to set different color for each route in the map. I have two routes.